# Why does Tkinter throw a TypeError, but only on some computers?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple script that uses a tkinter optionmenu to show comm ports.

```
ports = list_available_ports()
comm_drop_val = tk.StringVar()
comm_drop_val.set("Ports")
global comm_drop
comm_drop = tk.OptionMenu(root,comm_drop_val,*ports)
```

When running in PyCharm it works fine. It also works on two different PCs (running as an .exe using py2exe). On two *other* machines however, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "main.py", line 505, in <module>
    File "main.py", line 365, in main
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'value'
```

I'm assuming this is becuase the OptionMenu definition has a required argument called 'value', but why is it only required *sometimes*?

```
def __init__(self,
         master: Misc | None,
         variable: StringVar,
         value: str,
         *values: str,
         command: (StringVar) -> Any | None = ...) -> None
```

I don't actually want a default value there. I only want to display what is in *values on the drop down. If I put ports[0] there, it displays COM3 twice.

Comment: Apparently, `list_available_ports()` returned an empty list on the problem machines.  You'll need to handle that case specially, since there's nothing for your menu to display.

Comment: Ah, yeah. I forgot that actually did happen. That makes more sense now. Thanks!

Comment: Why not answer your own question?